# SFTP fails where SSH works

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm running a win7 x64 PC and 
I've got a problem when i tried to connect a internal server on sftp with:

```
ip      : 172.22.1.39:22
username: root
password: *******
```

the error is the following (FileZilla):

```
Status: Connecting to 172.22.1.39 ...
Answer: fzSftp started, protocol_version = 2
Command: open "root@172.22.1.39" 22
Command: Pass: *******
Error: Authentication failed.
Error: Critical Error: Can not connect to server
```

ps: the log is translated from italian.

It's not the client because also TotalCommander fails.
But using SSH (PuTTY) the connection goes well.

The "funny" part this is if i change workstation the SFTP connection works.

Anyone knows about this issue?

Thanks,

If any info is needing just comment.

Comment: Do you have some special characters in the password? Like accented Italian letter?

Comment: onli ascii lowercase characters...

Comment: Can you look at the sshd log file on the remote server?

Comment: Where i can find this log?

Comment: Problem solved... WinSCP works fine